# the page post back to the inital state when data loads from the drop down list

Tags: asp.net, postback

i have a page named loginsecurity_test.aspx.there are 3 radio buttons on it when user selects one button only one login form displays.for example when i select individual user button a form is displayed.i have to select a customer number from a drop down list.when i select a customer number from it the page post back and instead of taking to the form again it go back to the inital stage where only three radio buttons are being displayed.the language is vb.net for the radio button functionality i am using javascript

Comment: Consider case sensitivity, structuring and punctuation to make your question more readable.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you need to check [Page.IsPostback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) in your page load event so that you can track the state of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to DataBind the DropDownList in the PageLoad event like this

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //DataBind the DropDownList
        }
  }
```